# name for matrix with eigenvalues equal to diagonal elements

Tags: matrices, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

I am working with an $n \times n$ matrix $A$ that has an interesting property. For $k=1,2,\ldots,n$, either the $k^\text{th}$ column or $k^\text{th}$ row of $A$ (or both) is a positive scalar multiple of the $k^\text{th}$ standard basis vector. In the cofactor expansion of $\det(A - \lambda I)$, one may thus expand strategically on either rows or columns to find $\det(A - \lambda I) = \prod_{k=1}^n (A_{kk} - \lambda)$. Similar to a triangular matrix, the eigenvalues of $A$ are evidently the elements on its main diagonal.

In case it helps, here's a concrete example (which coincidentally is also a left stochastic matrix and an inverse $M$-matrix):
$$A = \left[ \begin{array}{cccc} 
\frac{2}{3} & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
\frac{1}{5} & 1 & \frac{3}{20} & 0 \\
0 & 0 & \frac{3}{4} & 0 \\
\frac{2}{15} & 0 & \frac{1}{10} & 1
\end{array} \right].$$

Is there name for matrices like what I described? Thanks in advance.